# Yet another complex MySQL ordering

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting

I've searched SO for the answer, but it seems my particular case is just a bit different than the rest.

Basically my data consists of some "master" records with a "position" (acts_as_list in RoR), and then any number of "customized" records with a custom_position to mirror the master position.  The desired result is to retrieve a set containing the master + custom records, ordered by master1, custom1..., master2, custom2...,

The master records will have a NULL custom_position; the custom records will have a custom_position equal to their master's position.

**source data, unsorted:**

```
name        sort_a   sort_b
====        ======   ======
Lorem       1        NULL
ipsum       2        NULL
dolor       3        NULL
Lorem foo   4        1
ipsum foo   5        2
dolor foo   6        3
Lorem bar   7        1
ipsum bar   8        2
dolor bar   9        3
Lorem duck  10       1
ipsum duck  11       2
dolor duck  12       3
```

**desired sorting:**

```
name        sort_a   sort_b
====        ======   ======
Lorem       1        NULL
Lorem foo   4        1
Lorem bar   7        1
Lorem duck  10       1
ipsum       2        NULL
ipsum foo   5        2
ipsum bar   8        2
ipsum duck  11       2
dolor       3        NULL
dolor foo   6        3
dolor bar   9        3
dolor duck  12       3
```

**closest I've gotten:**
  order by coalesce(sort_a, sort_b) asc

```
name        sort_a   sort_b
====        ======   ======
Lorem foo   4        1
Lorem bar   7        1
Lorem duck  10       1
Lorem       1        NULL
ipsum foo   5        2
ipsum bar   8        2
ipsum duck  11       2
ipsum       2        NULL
dolor foo   6        3
dolor bar   9        3
dolor duck  12       3
dolor       3        NULL
```

Any idea how I can achieve the desired sorting in an ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        COALESCE(sort_b, sort_a), sort_a
```

A query to check:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  'Lorem' AS name, 1 AS sort_a, NULL AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ipsum' AS name, 2 AS sort_a, NULL AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'dolor' AS name, 3 AS sort_a, NULL AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Lorem foo' AS name, 4 AS sort_a, 1 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ipsum foo' AS name, 5 AS sort_a, 2 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'dolor foo' AS name, 6 AS sort_a, 3 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Lorem bar' AS name, 7 AS sort_a, 1 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ipsum bar' AS name, 8 AS sort_a, 2 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'dolor bar' AS name, 9 AS sort_a, 3 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Lorem duck' AS name, 10 AS sort_a, 1 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ipsum duck' AS name, 11 AS sort_a, 2 AS sort_b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'dolor duck' AS name, 12 AS sort_a, 3 AS sort_b
        ) q
ORDER BY
        COALESCE(sort_b, sort_a), sort_a
```

Comment: Examine row 8 in the final listing in the OP, Ipsum,2,NULL will end up in front of Lorem Foo,4,1.  No good.

Comment: @Ken Downs, perhaps Quassnoi fixed it, because the test query returns the proper order for me now.

Comment: Who am I to argue with success? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, but can be done with a UNION.  The first clause goes for the NULL rows, the 2nd clause goes for the others:

```
select name
     , sort_a
     , sort_a as sort_b
  from myTable
 where sort_b is null
 UNION ALL
select name
     , sort_a
     , sort_b
  from myTable
 where sort_b is NOT null
 order by 3,2
```

Note that in a UNION query, you sort using column numbers instead of names.